# Rest authentication with python social auth and Satellizer

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, satellizer

I am trying to enable authentication in my single page angular app using [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) as client on frontend and [python social auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) on backend using [django rest framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework). The main problem is that I want to use **JWT** instead of session authentication.

I have tried passing the response I get after the user confirms the popup window to `social/complete/backend` (python social auth view) but with no luck.

In satellizer for google configuration I put:

```
        $authProvider.google({
            clientId:'609163425136-1i7b7jlr4j4hlqtnb1gk3al2kagavcjm.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            url: 'social/complete/google-oauth2/',
            optionalUrlParams: ['display', 'state'],
            state: function() {
                return Math.random();
            }
        });
```

The problems I encounter are in python social auth:

> Missing needed parameter **state**

for **google-oauth2**
 and

> Missing needed parameter **code**

for **facebook**.

That is very strange to me because those parameters are present in the request payload and I can get then in my own custom view.

---

The closest I have come to a solution is writing my own view in which I can accept the parameter `state` normally.

This is my view which handles the response and creates a new jwt token using the [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt):

```
class SocialAuthView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    social_serializer = SocialAuthSerializer
    user_serializer = None

    def post(self, request):
        access_token_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
        people_api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect'

        from django.conf import settings
        payload = dict(client_id=request.data['clientId'],
                       redirect_uri=request.data['redirectUri'],
                       client_secret=settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET,
                       code=request.data['code'],
                       grant_type='authorization_code')

        # Step 1. Exchange authorization code for access token.
        import requests
        import json
        r = requests.post(access_token_url, data=payload)
        token = json.loads(r.text)
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token['access_token'])}

        # Step 2. Retrieve information about the current user.
        r = requests.get(people_api_url, headers=headers)
        profile = json.loads(r.text)

        try:
            user = User.objects.filter(email=profile['email'])[0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        import jwt
        from rest_framework_jwt.utils import jwt_payload_handler, jwt_encode_handler
        if user:
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
            token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
            return Response({'token': token.decode('unicode_escape')},
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        u = User.objects.create(username=profile['name'], first_name=profile['given_name'],
                                last_name=profile['family_name'], email=profile['email'])
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return Response({'Bearer': token.decode('unicode_escape')},
                        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I mean, it works, but I don't get all the benefits that I would get if I could implement it with python social auth. Maybe there is a way to authenticate with python social auth calling some functions like **do_auth** from this view?

It amazes me how much I struggle with this problem.

All help is welcome.

**tl,dr**: How to implement **angular single page** application using **Satellizer**, **django-rest-framework**, **python social auth** and **JWT**?

Answer (score 5):

Not quite an answer, but I don't have sufficient reputation to comment.
I've been trying to do something similar. Satellizer works well with DRF's djoser module for email/pass token auth.
As for the social aspect, I'm finding OAuth2 quite complicated. You might want to look at the following project (no relation to me), it seems to be trying to implement just that (angularjs-satellizer/psa/jwt):

https://github.com/hsr-ba-fs15-dat/opendatahub

specifically:
https://github.com/hsr-ba-fs15-dat/opendatahub/blob/master/src/main/python/authentication/views.py

Comment: Feel free to convert to a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is gold. I implemented something similar but consider dropping python social auth altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I got the points to comment now. I'll convert it to a comment as soon as I figure out how to (looks incredibly hidden../impossible?!.). It would be better if answers included code and best practice, but that particular repo may be quite a good place to start a discussion.

Comment: No need to convert to comment. It is a valuable answer.